# Switch between Users in FirebaseUser - FirebaseAuth

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I've been working on an Admin Control panel on Android. inside which admin can add and disable the users.
Suppose the admin uid is I4YnygVk2eaCLEJbCiCLiWlo13as

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailid, password)
.addOnCompleteListener(UserManagement.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
        Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful()+"uid"+mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
        //here the Uid is changed to the new registered user i.e RlhiQxMibWYA1NaqlN9JdFZ8ocK2.

        AuthCredential credential = EmailAuthProvider
            .getCredential("a@a.com", "123456");

            firebaseUser.reauthenticate(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

        //here what i need is getUid() should print the admin's uid(I4YnygVk2eaCLEJbCiCLiWlo13as), and not the newly created uid.
                            Log.d(TAG, "User re-authenticated."+firebaseUser.getUid())                                    database.getReference("users/"+mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("active").setValue(true);
                        }
                    });

    }        
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your user creation is successful call this method

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
```

this would signout the newly created user and then you can signin with admin credentials.